# testing asynchronous useEffect in hooks with testing-library/preact

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, preact, vitest

I'm working on a preact hook that onMount fetches some data from the backend via a webSocket to then set it's initial state. The implementation by now looks something like this:

```
import {useContext, useEffect, useState} from "preact/compat";

import {useMessages, useTranslation, useWebSocket} from "helper/hooks";

import {IExternal} from "./interface";
import {CMD} from "./CMD";

export const useCodes = () => {
    const {post} = useWebSocket();
    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const {error} = useMessages();

    const [externals, setExternals] = useState<IExternal[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getExternals();
    }, []);

    const getExternals = () => {
        post<never, IExternal[]>(CMD.GetExternals)
            .then(setExternals)
            .catch(() => {
                error(t("externals.error"));
            });
    };

    return {
        getExternals,
        externals
    }
}
```

in my test suite i now mock the webSocket hook to test for the initial fetch however it seems like that the test is evaluated before the promises from my webSocket settle. I tried different solutions already like waiting for a few miliseconds with something like `await setTimeout(Promise.resolve, 200)` and also tried the `act` method from `@testing-library/preact` but with no success by now.

The tests look like this atm:

```
import {waitFor, renderHook} from "@testing-library/preact";
import {h} from "preact";
import {ChangeLog} from "helper/Provider";

import {useCodes} from "./useCodes";

const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => {
    return {
        webSocket: {
            ws: vi.fn(),
            post: vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve()),
            subscribe: vi.fn(),
            unsubscribe: vi.fn(),
        },
    }
});

vi.mock("helper/hooks/useWebSocket", () => ({
    useWebSocket: () => mocks.webSocket,
}));

describe("useCodes - Default", () => {

    afterEach(() => {
        vi.resetAllMocks();
    })

    test("Should fetch data on mount", async () => {
        mocks.webSocket.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve([{id: "1", name: "external-1"}]));

        const {result} = renderHook(() => useCodes());

        await waitFor(() => {
            // this works just fine - in actual implementation there are a few more commands happening => expect.arrayContaining
            expect(mocks.webSocket.post.mock.calls).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([["getExternalsCommand"]]))

            // data is undefined
            expect(result.current.externals).toEqual([{id: "1", name: "external-1"}])
        })
    })
})
```

with this setup the `externals` property is undefined when i want to assert the result. If i use the sleep or act function mentioned earlier the state is still an empty array. Is there a better or proper approach to wait for the initial `useEffect`?